# Media player is not worklng is Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Media player is not working in android kotlin.
i have created one alarm manager to whenever click the button the alarm will run

```
private lateinit var mp: MediaPlayer
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm)
        mp.start()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

whenever i clicked button the toast is generated but alarm music is not work........

Answer (score 0):

https://pastebin.com/bzE6x2d3

Code for media player and spinner

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var musicSpinner: Spinner
    private lateinit var playButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        musicSpinner = findViewById(R.id.musicSpinner)
        playButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton)

        // Add music options to the spinner
        val musicOptions = arrayOf("song1", "song2", "song3")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, musicOptions)
        musicSpinner.adapter = adapter
//
        // Initialize MediaPlayer
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1) // Default to the first song

        // Set OnClickListener for the play button
        playButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.pause()
                playButton.text = "Play Music"
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start()
                playButton.text = "Pause Music"
            }
        }
//
//        // Set OnItemSelectedListener for the spinner to change the currently playing music
        musicSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>?, selectedItemView: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selectedSong = musicOptions[position]
                val resourceName = "raw/$selectedSong"
                val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(resourceName, null, packageName)

                mediaPlayer.stop()
                mediaPlayer.release()
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity2, resourceId)
                playButton.text = "Pause Music"
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>?) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mediaPlayer.release()
    }
}
```

Alternate media player with pause and play button

```
package com.example.audio_video

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var seekBar : SeekBar
    private lateinit var runnable: Runnable
    private lateinit var handler: Handler
    private var mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.sbClapping)
        seekBar.isEnabled = true
        handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.love1975)
        val play = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabPlay)
        play.setOnClickListener{
            if(mediaPlayer==null){
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.love1975)
                    initialiseSeekBar()

            }
            mediaPlayer?.start()
        }

        val pause = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabPause)
        pause.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer?.pause()
        }

        val stop = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabStop)
        stop.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.release()
            mediaPlayer = null
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
            seekBar.progress = 0

        }
    }

    private fun initialiseSeekBar()
    {
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                if(fromUser) mediaPlayer?.seekTo(progress)
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            }

        })
        seekBar.max = mediaPlayer!!.duration
        runnable = Runnable {
            seekBar.progress= mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition
            handler.postDelayed(runnable , 1000)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable , 1000)
    }


}
```

xml file for above code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clapping"
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="223dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.236"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/claps" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbClapping"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.587" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPlayed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.123"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.725"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/playarrow" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabPause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.725"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pause" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.87"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.725"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/stop" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```